# Initialize Reactjs component with attributes

Tags: reactjs

I would like to extend my classic HTML app with some ReactJS

My can be simplified to:

```
<body>
  <my-component property="abc" />
  <my-component property="123" />
</body>
```

How can I access value of `property` inside React.Component?

Comment: `this.props.property` ... Have a look at the react documentation for an introduction: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html .

Comment: I have most of my HTML rendered on a backend server and I would like to make some additional more interactive features with React components. Problem I have is how to pass data from static HTML to React component. With backbone I would use data-* properties but I can not figure out how to access it (data on container element)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question, but if what you want is to extend some HTML component you should use spread atributes. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes

Customizing an image:

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const MyImage = (props) => {
  // get your customized atribute
  const {log, alt, ...properties} = props;

  // Do wherever you want
  console.log(log);

  // Pass the rest to the image  
  return <img alt={alt} {...properties}/>;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyImage log="logging action"
      alt="React logo"
      style={{ width: "400px", height: "400px"}}
      src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/react.svg" />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Note**: To understand why the `alt` atribute wasn't passed with other properties access this link https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/7

Comment: I have most of my HTML rendered on a backend server and I would like to make some additional more interactive features with React components. Problem I have is how to pass data from static HTML to React component. With backbone I would use data-* properties but I can not figure out how to access it (data on container element)